# Merlin's Wisdom and proverbs

Tags: story-identification, merlin

Many years ago I saw a Merlin's movie where he used a proverb something like this:

> *Is not the sword who makes the knight!!!* ( this is not the correct sentence, but similar).

Could someone tell the me movie where he says this? Or perhaps point me some other "reference" (movie/book/etc..) where the similar meaning is used?

**UPDATE #1**

I don't think the specific movie I remember is the [Excalibur](http://uk.imdb.com/title/tt0082348/). The few bits and pieces I still remember tell me that this may be a "kids/teenager" movie, and perhaps with a "recent years story line" with some kind "Merlin" or the "kid" that travels time. I am really not sure. I think I saw this movie more than 15 years ago (the movie may be older).

Comment: Can you define 'many'?  It may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kids/teenager thing makes me think it might be one of the versions of ["A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Connecticut_Yankee_in_King_Arthur%27s_Court). There's been more than one movie made of it. Was Merlin played by Michael York? That would be [this version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115030/), which fits the time frame, but I haven't actually seen it, so I don't know if your quote is in there.

Comment: I've searched for quotes of that movie and I found this: "It does not take a sword and stone to make a hero.", it is not exactly as I remember (the mind play tricks on us), but the meaning is there, so perhaps this is the movie. And since I do not find some other plausible movie, I choose your answer and the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly [Excalibur](http://uk.imdb.com/title/tt0082348/quotes), with the very strange Nicol Williamson as Merlin.

Comment: Scanning through the [script](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/e/excalibur-script-transcript-arthur-merlin.html), there doesn't appear to be a similar quote.

Answer (score -1):

[A Kid in King Arthur's Court (1995)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Kid_in_King_Arthur's_Court)

I'm only looking to help this person find what they are looking for.

http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0113538/

IMDb quotes from "A Kid in King Arthur's Court http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0113538/quotes

King Arthur: Let all who witness this know: It does not take a sword and stone to make a hero.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately this question has already been answered correctly, so this answer is unlikely to get much attention. Also, I tried clicking on the link and couldn't find any Wikipedia article of that name. Please could you edit in some more detail (e.g. by quoting from Wikipedia) about this film, to make it clearer how it fits the description in the question? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here, since if the link goes dead the answer becomes essentially useless.